# Temperature Converter With Modern C++

Tags: c++, c++14

Inspired by an earlier [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102691/temperature-converter) I've made a temperature converter that can convert from one temperature to another and optionally output a series of conversions.

This was made in Visual Studio 2015 but it also compiles with g++ and clang++ on Debian with no warnings.

#### Usage

```
tc.exe -40 c f

Celcius           | Fahrenheit
------------------+------------------
           -40.00 |            -40.00
```

or

```
tc.exe -40 c f 10 10
Celcius           | Fahrenheit
------------------+------------------
           -40.00 |            -40.00
           -30.00 |            -22.00
           -20.00 |             -4.00
           -10.00 |             14.00
             0.00 |             32.00
            10.00 |             50.00
```

Where the arguments are:

```
Usage: tc.exe Degrees InitialUnit ConvertedUnit [InitialUnitStepSize InitialUnitUpperBoundInclusive]
```

#### stdafx.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
```

#### Temperature.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"

namespace hest {

enum class TemperatureUnit
{
    Invalid,
    Celcius,
    Fahrenheit,
    Kelvin,
    Rankine,
};

class TemperatureData;
class Kelvin;

class Temperature {
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Temperature> UniqueTemperature;

    static std::string ToShortString(TemperatureUnit const unit);
    static std::string ToString(TemperatureUnit const unit);
    static TemperatureUnit StringToUnit(std::string const & unit);
    static TemperatureUnit CharToUnit(char unit);
    static UniqueTemperature CreateTemperature(double degrees, TemperatureUnit unit);
    static UniqueTemperature Convert(Temperature const & from, TemperatureUnit const to);

    double degrees() const;
    TemperatureUnit unit() const;


    std::string ToString() const;

    virtual Kelvin ToKelvin() const = 0;

protected:
    Temperature(double degrees, TemperatureUnit unit);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<TemperatureData> data_;
};

class Kelvin final : public Temperature {
public:
    Kelvin(double degrees);

    Kelvin ToKelvin() const;
    UniqueTemperature ConvertTo(TemperatureUnit const unit) const;
};

class Celcius final : public Temperature {
public:
    Celcius(double degrees);

    Kelvin ToKelvin() const;
};

class Rankine final : public Temperature {
public:
    Rankine(double degrees);

    Kelvin ToKelvin() const;
};

class Fahrenheit final : public Temperature {
public:
    Fahrenheit(double degrees);

    Kelvin ToKelvin() const;
};

inline bool operator==(Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return lhs.degrees() == rhs.degrees(); }
inline bool operator!=(Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return !operator==(lhs, rhs); }
inline bool operator< (Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return lhs.degrees() < rhs.degrees(); }
inline bool operator> (Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return  operator< (rhs, lhs); }
inline bool operator<=(Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return !operator> (lhs, rhs); }
inline bool operator>=(Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return !operator< (lhs, rhs); }

inline bool operator==(Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) { return lhs.ToKelvin() == rhs.ToKelvin(); }
inline bool operator!=(Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) { return !operator==(lhs, rhs); }
inline bool operator< (Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) { return lhs.ToKelvin() < rhs.ToKelvin(); }
inline bool operator> (Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) { return  operator< (rhs, lhs); }
inline bool operator<=(Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) { return !operator> (lhs, rhs); }
inline bool operator>=(Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) { return !operator< (lhs, rhs); }

inline Kelvin operator+(Kelvin const & lhs, double rhs) { return Kelvin(lhs.degrees() + rhs); }
inline Kelvin operator+(Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return Kelvin(lhs.degrees() + rhs.degrees()); }
inline Kelvin operator-(Kelvin const & lhs, double rhs) { return Kelvin(lhs.degrees() - rhs); }
inline Kelvin operator-(Kelvin const & lhs, Kelvin const & rhs) { return Kelvin(lhs.degrees() - rhs.degrees()); }

inline Temperature::UniqueTemperature operator+(Temperature const & lhs, double rhs) {
    return Temperature::CreateTemperature(lhs.degrees() + rhs, lhs.unit());
}
inline Temperature::UniqueTemperature operator+(Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) {
    if (lhs.unit() == rhs.unit()) {
        return Temperature::CreateTemperature(lhs.degrees() + rhs.degrees(), lhs.unit());
    }

    auto converted = Temperature::Convert(lhs, rhs.unit());
    return Temperature::CreateTemperature(rhs.degrees() + converted->degrees(), rhs.unit());
}
inline Temperature::UniqueTemperature operator-(Temperature const & lhs, double rhs) {
    return Temperature::CreateTemperature(lhs.degrees() - rhs, lhs.unit());
}
inline Temperature::UniqueTemperature operator-(Temperature const & lhs, Temperature const & rhs) {
    if (lhs.unit() == rhs.unit()) {
        return Temperature::CreateTemperature(lhs.degrees() - rhs.degrees(), lhs.unit());
    }

    auto converted = Temperature::Convert(lhs, rhs.unit());
    return Temperature::CreateTemperature(rhs.degrees() - converted->degrees(), rhs.unit());
}

}
```

#### Temperature.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "temperature.h"

namespace hest {

constexpr double kCelciusToKelvinOffset = 273.15;
constexpr double kFahrenheitToRankineOffset = 459.67;

static inline double RankineToKelvin(double rankineDegrees) {
    return rankineDegrees * 5.0 / 9.0;
}

static inline double KelvinToRankine(double kelvinDegrees) {
    return kelvinDegrees * 9.0 / 5.0;
}

class TemperatureData {
private:
    double const degrees_;
    TemperatureUnit const unit_;
public:
    TemperatureData(double degrees, TemperatureUnit unit) : degrees_(degrees), unit_(unit) {
        if (!std::isfinite(degrees)) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Degrees must be finite");
        }
        if (unit == TemperatureUnit::Invalid) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid unit");
        }
    }

    double degrees() const { return degrees_; }
    TemperatureUnit unit() const { return unit_; }
};

Temperature::Temperature(double degrees, TemperatureUnit unit) : data_(std::make_shared<TemperatureData>(degrees, unit)) {}

Kelvin::Kelvin(double degrees) : Temperature(degrees, TemperatureUnit::Kelvin) { }
Celcius::Celcius(double degrees) : Temperature(degrees, TemperatureUnit::Celcius) { }
Rankine::Rankine(double degrees) : Temperature(degrees, TemperatureUnit::Rankine) { }
Fahrenheit::Fahrenheit(double degrees) : Temperature(degrees, TemperatureUnit::Fahrenheit) { }

Kelvin Kelvin::ToKelvin() const {
    return Kelvin(degrees());
}
Kelvin Celcius::ToKelvin() const {
    return Kelvin(degrees() + kCelciusToKelvinOffset);
}
Kelvin Rankine::ToKelvin() const {
    return Kelvin(RankineToKelvin(degrees()));
}
Kelvin Fahrenheit::ToKelvin() const {
    return Kelvin(RankineToKelvin(degrees() + kFahrenheitToRankineOffset));
}

std::string Temperature::ToShortString(TemperatureUnit const unit)
{
    switch (unit)
    {
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Kelvin:
        return "K";
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Celcius:
        return "C";
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Rankine:
        return "R";
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Fahrenheit:
        return "F";
    default:
        return "";
    }
}

std::string Temperature::ToString(TemperatureUnit const unit)
{
    switch (unit)
    {
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Kelvin:
        return "Kelvin";
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Celcius:
        return "Celcius";
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Rankine:
        return "Rankine";
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Fahrenheit:
        return "Fahrenheit";
    default:
        return "";
    }
}

TemperatureUnit Temperature::StringToUnit(std::string const & unit) {
    auto length = unit.length();

    switch (length)
    {
    case 1:
        return CharToUnit(unit[0]);
    case 6:
        if (unit.compare("Kelvin") == 0 || unit.compare("kelvin") == 0) {
            return TemperatureUnit::Kelvin;
        }
    case 7:
        if (unit.compare("Celcius") == 0 || unit.compare("celcius") == 0) {
            return TemperatureUnit::Celcius;
        }
        if (unit.compare("Rankine") == 0 || unit.compare("rankine") == 0) {
            return TemperatureUnit::Rankine;
        }
    case 10:
        if (unit.compare("Fahrenheit") == 0 || unit.compare("fahrenheit") == 0) {
            return TemperatureUnit::Fahrenheit;
        }
    }

    return TemperatureUnit::Invalid;
}

TemperatureUnit Temperature::CharToUnit(char unit) {
    switch (unit)
    {
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        return TemperatureUnit::Celcius;
    case 'f':
    case 'F':
        return TemperatureUnit::Fahrenheit;
    case 'k':
    case 'K':
        return TemperatureUnit::Kelvin;
    case 'r':
    case 'R':
        return TemperatureUnit::Rankine;
    default:
        return TemperatureUnit::Invalid;
    }
}

auto Temperature::CreateTemperature(double degrees, TemperatureUnit unit) -> UniqueTemperature {
    switch (unit)
    {
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Kelvin:
        return std::make_unique<Kelvin>(degrees);
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Celcius:
        return std::make_unique<Celcius>(degrees);
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Rankine:
        return std::make_unique<Rankine>(degrees);
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Fahrenheit:
        return std::make_unique<Fahrenheit>(degrees);
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid unit");
    }
}

auto Temperature::Convert(Temperature const & from, TemperatureUnit const to) -> UniqueTemperature {
    auto kelvin = from.ToKelvin();
    return kelvin.ConvertTo(to);
}

double Temperature::degrees() const {
    return data_->degrees();
}

TemperatureUnit Temperature::unit() const {
    return data_->unit();
}

std::string Temperature::ToString() const {
    std::ostringstream format_stream;
    format_stream << degrees() << ToShortString(unit());
    return format_stream.str();
}

auto Kelvin::ConvertTo(TemperatureUnit const unit) const -> UniqueTemperature {
    switch (unit)
    {
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Kelvin:
        return std::make_unique<Kelvin>(degrees());
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Celcius:
        return std::make_unique<Celcius>(degrees() - kCelciusToKelvinOffset);
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Rankine:
        return std::make_unique<Rankine>(KelvinToRankine(degrees()));
    case hest::TemperatureUnit::Fahrenheit:
        return std::make_unique<Fahrenheit>(KelvinToRankine(degrees()) - kFahrenheitToRankineOffset);
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid unit");
    }
}

}
```

#### TemperatureConverter.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "temperature.h"
#include <iomanip>

constexpr int kMaxDigits = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10;
constexpr int kColumnWidth = kMaxDigits + 2;
constexpr auto kRowSeparator = " | ";
static const auto kRowSeparatorLength = std::strlen(kRowSeparator);

std::string PrintResultHeader(hest::TemperatureUnit const initial, hest::TemperatureUnit const converted) {
    std::ostringstream format_stream;
    format_stream << std::left;
    format_stream << std::setw(kColumnWidth) << hest::Temperature::ToString(initial);
    format_stream << std::setw(0) << kRowSeparator;
    format_stream << std::setw(kColumnWidth) << hest::Temperature::ToString(converted);

    auto column_header_separator = std::string(kColumnWidth + kRowSeparatorLength / 2, '-');
    format_stream << std::setw(0) << "\n" << column_header_separator;
    if (kRowSeparatorLength % 2 == 1) {
        format_stream << "+";
    }
    format_stream << column_header_separator;

    return format_stream.str();
}

std::string PrintResultRow(hest::Temperature::UniqueTemperature const & initial, hest::Temperature::UniqueTemperature const & converted) {
    std::ostringstream format_stream;
    format_stream << std::right << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;
    format_stream << std::setw(kColumnWidth) << initial->degrees();
    format_stream << std::setw(0) << kRowSeparator;
    format_stream << std::setw(kColumnWidth) << converted->degrees();

    return format_stream.str();
}

template<typename TResult> bool TryParse(std::string const & input, TResult & result) {
    std::istringstream input_stream(input);
    input_stream >> result;
    return !input_stream.fail() && input_stream.eof();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (!(argc == 4 || argc == 6)) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " Degrees InitialUnit ConvertedUnit [InitialUnitStepSize InitialUnitUpperBoundInclusive]" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    bool has_errors = false;

    auto degrees_argument = std::string(argv[1]);
    double degrees = 0;
    if (!TryParse(degrees_argument, degrees)) {
        std::cerr << "Degrees: " << degrees_argument << " is not a valid number" << std::endl;
        has_errors = true;
    }

    auto initial_unit_argument = std::string(argv[2]);
    auto initial_unit = hest::Temperature::StringToUnit(initial_unit_argument);
    if (initial_unit == hest::TemperatureUnit::Invalid) {
        std::cerr << "InitialUnit: " << initial_unit_argument << " is not a valid unit" << std::endl;
        has_errors = true;
    }

    auto converted_unit_argument = std::string(argv[3]);
    auto converted_unit = hest::Temperature::StringToUnit(converted_unit_argument);
    if (converted_unit == hest::TemperatureUnit::Invalid) {
        std::cerr << "ConvertedUnit: " << converted_unit_argument << " is not a valid unit" << std::endl;
        has_errors = true;
    }

    /* step_size and upper_bound are initialized such that if they're not specified
       the conversion loop will run exactly once. */
    double step_size = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double upper_bound = degrees;
    if (argc == 6) {
        auto step_size_argument = std::string(argv[4]);
        if (!TryParse(step_size_argument, step_size)) {
            std::cerr << "InitialUnitStepSize: " << step_size_argument << " is not a valid number" << std::endl;
            has_errors = true;
        }
        if (!has_errors && step_size <= 0) {
            std::cerr << "InitialUnitStepSize must be positive" << std::endl;
            has_errors = true;
        }

        auto upper_bound_argument = std::string(argv[5]);
        if (!TryParse(upper_bound_argument, upper_bound)) {
            std::cerr << "InitialUnitUpperBoundInclusive: " << upper_bound_argument << " is not a valid number" << std::endl;
            has_errors = true;
        }
        if (!has_errors && upper_bound <= 0) {
            std::cerr << "InitialUnitUpperBoundInclusive must be greater than Degrees" << std::endl;
            has_errors = true;
        }
    }

    if (has_errors) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try
    {
        std::cout << PrintResultHeader(initial_unit, converted_unit) << std::endl;

        for (auto initial_temperature = hest::Temperature::CreateTemperature(degrees, initial_unit); 
             initial_temperature->degrees() <= upper_bound; 
             initial_temperature = *initial_temperature + step_size) 
        {
            auto converted_temperature = hest::Temperature::Convert(*initial_temperature, converted_unit);
            std::cout << PrintResultRow(initial_temperature, converted_temperature) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I see a lot more `->` than is nice. Which means you have pointers. This seems overcomplicated. Use normal objects rather than pointers (even if you wrap them in smart pointers).

Comment: Celcius should be Celsius.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I would have used a class hierarchy to represent the different types of temperature. In the end they represent the same thing (the amount of energy in a system). You should pick a unit to store that data in then covert all types to this global unit.

```
class Temperature
{
    double kelvin;
    public:
       // Explicit: We don't want auto-conversion.
       explicit Temperature(double kelvin)
           : kelvin(kelvin)
       {}
 };
```

Then write `make_temp_from_X()` functions that convert a particular scale to your chosen form.

```
 Temperature make_temp_from_kelvin(double k)  {return Temperature(k);}
 Temperature make_temp_from_celcius{double c) {return Temperature(c-273.15);}
 ... etc
```

The cost of passing an object of type `Temperature` around is the same cost as passing a double around (so you don't really need to worry about that).

Comment: But then I don't get to play with smart pointers and some of the other new features ;)